# Should 'one' be considered an article?

Tags: definite-articles, indefinite-articles, zero-article

> There is but one king, and I am one.

Here, the 'one' at the end of the sentence stands for 'one king' and 'one' is not specifying (in this particular place) a numeral. It is implying 'I am that one' or, more specifically 'I am that one king'.

Therefore, should 'one', when used in this way, not be considered an article with a well deserved place in the much documented sequence :

> zero ... some ... a/an ... the ... null

And, if so, where in the sequence should it be inserted ?

> Zero example : Who would wish to be king ?
>
> Some example : There are some kings, it is so.
>
> Indefinite example : I am a king and everyone knows it.
>
> Definite example : They respect the king, thus they respect me.
>
> Null example : Many wish to be king but the fact is that I am King.

---

Reference 1 :  [Stack Exchange - Why is 'any' not an article ?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373666/why-is-any-not-classified-as-an-article)

Reference 2 : [Acquisition of the Zero and Null Articles (Peter Master)](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/2kb4p9r0)

Comment: No, not an article, not a determiner, but a common noun functioning as subjective predicative complement. It is of course a pro-form - we understand it to mean "a king".

Comment: "A/an" and "one" are etymologically related, but cannot be used entirely interchangeably. For example, Big Mess Constructions: "such a grammatical example" vs. "such one ungrammatical example".

Comment: If it is a pro-form, but not a pronoun, then could it be considered as a pro-article ?

Comment: No, a pro-NP. That it is a common noun is evident from the fact that it can take a determiner ("I am the one") and it has an inflectional contrast between singular and plural ("we are the ones").

Comment: In the expression 'one is not amused' is 'one' a pronoun, meaning 'I am not amused' or is it an article, meaning 'one person (unspecified)' is not amused ? Is an unspecified numeral not (really) an article ?

Comment: In that example, "one" is a personal pronoun, a special kind of 3rd person pronoun.

Comment: [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one) lists one as an adjective, noun, and pronoun.

Comment: _One_ is the third person non-specific indefinite pronoun. Cf: _I'm looking for a policeman, but I can't find **him**_ (here _a policeman_ is a specific indefinite NP) vs _I'm looking for a policeman, but I can't find **one**_ (here it's non-specific).

Comment: I am looking for paper to write on; I was hoping to find some.' Is  not 'some' an article, in this place ?

Comment: I wouldn't say so. In English at leat, as far as I know the term "article" is not used for words that can stand on their own, like "some" in that sentence.

Comment: @sumelic I think that is the answer. 'One' can stand alone - unlike a/an/the - therefore it is not fulfilling the same function. Thank you.

Comment: @NigelJ Are you clear that the second "one" in your original example (_There is but one king, and I am **one**_) is a common noun, not a pronoun, for the two reasons I gave earlier?

Comment: @BillJ 'One is never alone with schizophrenia' demonstrates, I think, the breadth of its usage.

Comment: @NigelJ "One" belongs to three parts of speech. In _**One** is never alone with schizophrenia_, it is a straightforward 3rd person personal pronoun. In _There is but one king, and I am **one**_, it is a common noun. As a cardinal number in, for example, _**One** car rolled on its side_, it is a determinative. It's important to recognise the three different categories (parts of speech).

Comment: "There is but one king, and I am a." "There is but one king, and I am the." Neither of these work. So why does this sentence indicate to you that "one" should be considered an article in that position?

Comment: Of course “one” should be considered an article, as should “any” or “another” and no few other words, but they’re not. 

I think "There is but one king, and I am one" is a mistake, at best. There are complicated circumstances in which that could be forced to work and was that what you were asking?

"There is but one king, and I am he/him/it“ work because they don't misuse "one."

Quite clearly without a “that”, the final “one” does not stand for “one king”, nor is it implying “I am that one (king)”. Your search engine of choice will demonstrate that by failing to find examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [one](https://www.etymonline.com/word/one) and [a/an](https://www.etymonline.com/word/a) are etymologically related and often used in nearly the same way, only a/an is an article.

At a cursory glance, it would appear that their usage is still pretty similar:

> He is **a** king I trust.
>   He is **one** king I trust.

However, there is (at least) one big difference — you can only use one article at once:

> *He is **the a** king I trust.
>   He is **the one** king I trust.

Another example: ["**a one** Mr. Jeremiah Swigg"](https://books.google.com/books?id=9-deAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA35)

A smaller difference is that Big Mess Constructions only work with a/an:

> This is such **a** grammatical example.
>   *This is such **one** ungrammatical example.

For both of these reasons (and probably some others), *one* should not be considered an article.

Comment: What does your answer have to do with the OP's question, which was  about the second one in _There is but one king, and I am **one**_?