# Is usage of word "some" has the same meaning as indefinite article?

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-articles

Is that true that the indefinite article can be always replaced with word "some" and it will be nearly always the same meaning?

Examples:

> I have bought a house = I have bought some house
>
> I walked in the forest and have met a squirrel = I walked in the forest and have met some squirrel
>
> The sandwich contains a cheese = The sandwich contains some cheese

Am I correct?

Comment: This [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/425829/should-one-be-considered-an-article) and its answer deals with null-some-a/an-the-zero articles. 'Some' is in the 'spectrum' of English articles as documented by [Peter Masters](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/2kb4p9r0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's correct - or at least I can't think of a way it's not.  The "some" you are referring to is the some that is used to define some unspecified or unknown thing.  It is not the quantitative use of the word.  It sounds a little dorky sometimes, but it definitely works.

It even works in this wack sentence because of how lot can be defined:  I don't like a lot of people - I don't like some lot of people

Your second example is a bit odd.  It should read more like:  "I walked in the forest and met a/some squirrel."  This is not dependent on changing "a" to "some", it just doesn't make sense grammatically to use it that way because the first action of walking is in the past tense whereas the second action of meeting the squirrel is in present tense.  It could also be "I met a squirrel when I walked in the forest", or "While walking in the forest I met a squirrel".

Comment: Thanks! And what about the third one: "The sandwich contains a cheese = The sandwich contains some cheese"? Is this idiomatic usage? Are these sentences equal?

Comment: Nope, it's not idiomatic.  The reason "The sandwich contains a cheese" works is because "a cheese" can refer to a type of cheese.  Using "a cheese" to refer to amount of cheese would be improper usage because the amount is undefined and "cheese" is not a measurement unit.  Instead you would say  "The sandwich contains some cheese", which can easily refer to either amount or type.

Comment: I am little bit confused: *"The sandwich contains a cheese"* is not an idiomatic, but still meaningful and has the same meaning as with *"...some cheese"*?

Comment: While you could probably construct a scenario where "_The sandwich contains a cheese_" is _correct_, it almost always sounds wrong. In the context of what you might find in a sandwich (unless you put a whole cheese between two bits of bread), _cheese_ is an uncountable noun, so needs _some_ not _a_. If you mean it contains a _type_ of cheese, you'd either say that, or simply call it _a cheese sandwich_ (cf.  three-cheese macaroni -- a dish containing three [different] types of cheese).

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify.  "The sandwich contains some cheese" is idiomatic to English speakers, whereas "The sandwich contains a cheese" is not.  Tripe's explanation is beautiful!  Ha.